# spring boot delete an employee code confusion in controller

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-data

Here is my controller:

EmployeeController.java:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/employees/delete/{empNo}")
public String removeEmployee(@PathVariable("empNo") long empNo) {
    this.employeeService.deleteEmployee(empNo);
    return "redirect:/welcome/employees";
}
```

EmployeeRepository.java:

```
import com.hr.enity.Employee;
//import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import java.util.List;
import org.springframework.dao.DataAccessException;

@Repository
public interface EmployeeRepository {
    List<Employee> findAll() throws DataAccessException; 

    Employee findById(long empNo) throws DataAccessException;

    void save(Employee employee) throws DataAccessException;

    void delete(long empNo) throws DataAccessException;
}
```

EmployeeService.java:

```
import org.springframework.dao.DataAccessException;
import java.util.List;
import com.hr.enity.Employee;

public interface EmployeeService {
    Employee findEmployeeById(long empNo) throws DataAccessException;

    void saveEmployee(Employee employee) throws DataAccessException;

    List<Employee> findEmployees() throws DataAccessException;

    void deleteEmployee(long empNo) throws DataAccessException;
}
```

EmployeeServiceImpl.java:

```
@Service
public class EmployeeServiceImpl implements EmployeeService {
    private EmployeeRepository employeeRepository;

    @Autowired
    public EmployeeServiceImpl(EmployeeRepository employeeRepository) {
        this.employeeRepository = employeeRepository;
    }

    @Override
    public Employee findEmployeeById(long empNo) throws DataAccessException {
        return employeeRepository.findById(empNo);
    }

    @Override
    public List<Employee> findEmployees() throws DataAccessException {
        List<Employee> results = this.employeeRepository.findAll();
        return results;
    }

    @Override
    public void saveEmployee(Employee employee) throws DataAccessException {
        employeeRepository.save(employee);
    }

    @Override
    public void deleteEmployee(long empNo) throws DataAccessException {
        employeeRepository.delete(empNo);
    }
}
```

EmployeeJpaRepository.java:

```
@Repository
public interface EmployeeJpaRepository extends EmployeeRepository, CrudRepository<Employee, Long> {
    @Query("SELECT e from Employee e WHERE e.lastName='Demian' and e.gender='F'")
    List<Employee> findAll() throws DataAccessException;

    @Query("SELECT e FROM Employee e WHERE e.empNo =:empNo")
    Employee findById(@Param("empNo") long empNo); 
}
```

When I click on the delete, button it directs to http://localhost:8080/welcome/employees/delete/1234 but there is an error message:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property delete found for type Employee!

rg.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'employeeServiceImpl' defined in file [/home/manasa/Desktop/projects/employee-manager/target/classes/com/hr/service/EmployeeServiceImpl.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 0 of type [com.hr.repository.EmployeeRepository]: Error creating bean with name 'employeeJpaRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property delete found for type Employee!; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'employeeJpaRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property delete found for type Employee!
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:749) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:185) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
```

at times it's a white label error or compiler error

Comment: What's the point of `EmployeeRepository`? Delete the `EmployeeRepository` interface and inject `EmployeeJpaRepository` into your services.

Answer (score 2):

Delete your EmployeeRepository first, you don't need it. And change ServiceImpl like below. Also I'm guessing empNo is the primary key then, you don't need to write findById in EmployeeJpaRepository, there is findOne(id) available directly from CrudRepository to use.

In your case since its long you can call it as findOne(Long.toString(empNo))

```
@Service
public class EmployeeServiceImpl implements EmployeeService {

   @Autowired
    private EmployeeJpaRepository  employeeJpaRepository ;

    @Override
    public Employee findEmployeeById(long empNo) throws DataAccessException {
        return employeeJpaRepository.findById(empNo);
    }

    @Override
    public List<Employee> findEmployees() throws DataAccessException {
        return employeeJpaRepository.findAll();
    }

    @Override
    public void saveEmployee(Employee employee) throws DataAccessException {
        employeeRepository.save(employee);
    }

    @Override
    public void deleteEmployee(long empNo) throws DataAccessException {
        employeeRepository.delete(Long.toString(empNo));
    }
}
```

Comment: it says "The method delete(long) in the type EmployeeRepository is not applicable for the arguments (String)"

Comment: If you read my comment again, EmployeeRepository is not needed, delete it. You need to use employeeJpaRepository.delete(Long.toString(empNo) in your controller but again you are doing the same thing.

Comment: Why to write extra code when the framework is providing you what you want.?